# Can't process simple form submitted by jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

My **form**:

```
<form id="new-protocol-form" method="post" role="form">
  <textarea name="text"></textarea>
</form>
```

---

My jquery **ajax**:

```
$('#submitProtocol').click(
    function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:    "POST",
            url:     "newProtocol.php",
            data:    $('#new-protocol-form').serialize(),
            success: function() { alert{'ok'} },
            error:   function() { alert('error'); }
        });
    }
);
```

---

My **newProtocol.php**:

```
<script>
    alert(<?php echo $_POST['text']; ?>);
</script>
```

---

Alert window with 'ok' text triggered by ajax 'success' method is shown, but I can't get alert window with `$_POST['text']` value from newProtocol.php file. No error in javascript console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$_POST['text']`. You're using parentheses where you shouldn't be.

In addition, since you're using AJAX you probably don't want to navigate to the other page. Your alerts in your success function will never fire if you don't prevent the default behavior.

newProtocol.php

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['text'];
?>
```

jQuery

```
$('#submitProtocol').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // stop the default click behavior
        $.ajax({
            type:    "POST",
            url:     "newProtocol.php",
            data:    $('#new-protocol-form').serialize(),
            success: function(data) { 
                console.log(data); // show the text being returned 
            },
            error:   function() { console.log('error'); }
        });
    }
);
```

Also, [quit using `alert()`](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/) for getting return values and trouble-shooting.

Comment: Thanks, but still the same problem. And alert in my success function currently is fireing, as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Does it mean that all the html from newProtocol.php is stored in data variable?

Comment: Yes - any HTML you output in newProtocol.php will be in `data`. JavaScript in newProtocol.php *will not be executed*.

Comment: I outputted 'data' variable and it contains string with html from newProtocol.php

Comment: What do you want the output to be? If you need that page output there are a couple of things you can do.

Comment: I don't need any output, I just want to store datas to database. And if so I can append that output to html element with jquery .html() or .append();

Answer (score 0):

First, `$_POST` is not a function, it's an array. So it should be `$_POST['text']`. Also,

```
<script>
    alert(<?php $_POST('text'); ?>);
</script>
```

will not create an alert like you expect since an async request does not run any javascript in the target page.

Since you're trying to test if the AJAX is working, the best way is to check what was the date returned from that request. Example:

```
//...
success: function(data) { console.log(data) },
//...
```